# VBA Excel Change Content of another Cell based on content of one cell

Tags: vba, excel

Can you help me with this. The Excel looks something like this:

[image: Excel Workbook]

I hope to automate 2 tasks:

1. When cells in Column C contains word "processed" => clear content in corresponding cell in column A
2. When cells in Column C contains word "blue" => change corresponding cell in column B to 0

I have tried Offset, Looping and other various method but can't seem to get it right. Please help.

Comment: Please understand that Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, therefore you need to [edit] your question and show the code you have already tried and (1) tell us what your code does and what you expect it to do. (2) if any there are error messages you get and where. (3) What issues you got with your code and where you got stuck.

Comment: Please accept an answer if your goal has been achieved. (Click the green checkmark next to an answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `InStr`-Function to check if it contains the substring. For Further Informations look [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/instr.php).

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub removeprocessed()
Dim Nlines As Long
Dim i As Long
Nlines = Columns(1).Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Row
For i = 2 To Nlines
    If 0 <> InStr(1, Cells(i, 3).Value, "processed") Then
        Cells(i, 1).Value = ""
    End If
    If 0 <> InStr(1, Cells(i, 3).Value, "blue") Then
        Cells(i, 2).Value = 0
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Using InStr as proposed by @UGP

Comment: (1) If you post code you should follow the [VBA Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices) guide: e.g. always fully qualify Cells and Range (2) Never use Integer unless communicating with old APIs (instead always use Long): Excel has more rows than Integer can handle. (3) Setting a value as string `.Value = "0"` is never a good idea instead you should use `.Value = 0`  (4) I know you only want to help but I think we should not answer questions which are off-topic because asking for code only.

Comment: @PalimPalim Thank you so much for your help. Much appreciated

Comment: @Peh Noted on these. My apologies as I am new to the site.

Comment: @AidanWee If you use the code from PalimPalim make sure you don't use it as it is but change the things I mentioned in my comment above to not run into any issues later.